# Por que cuando destruyo un prefab en unity se destruyen todos

Tags: unity3d

Tengo un problema cree un enemigo en unity hice toda la lógica para que cuando lo golpe tres veces se destruya luego convertí ese enemigo en un prefab y lo puse varias veces por el mapa el problema es que cuando golpeo tres veces a un enemigo se destruye no solo ese si no todos no se si tenga que ver que use una variable static en el codigo de la barra de vida para comprobar desde el codigo de la lógica del enemigo si la barra de vida es cero entonces destruirlo, por que he leído que usar variables static puede causar problemas no se que pueda ser ayuda por favor

este es el codigo de la barra de vida:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BarraDeVidaEnemigo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Slider slider;
    public static bool enemigoDerrotado = false; 
    void Start()
    {
       slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (DañoAEnemigo.comprobanteDeVidaEnemigo == 3)
        {
            slider.value = 3;
        }
        else if (DañoAEnemigo.comprobanteDeVidaEnemigo == 2)
        {
            slider.value = 2;
        }
        else if (DañoAEnemigo.comprobanteDeVidaEnemigo == 1)
        {
            slider.value = 1;
        }
        else if (DañoAEnemigo.comprobanteDeVidaEnemigo == 0)
        {
            slider.value = 0;
            enemigoDerrotado = true;
        }

    }
}
```

y esta parte de codigo la uso desde otro script para eliminar al enemigo:

```
if (BarraDeVidaEnemigo.enemigoDerrotado)
 {
     Destroy(gameObject);
 }
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Si no muestras el código no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, okey entiendo mcuhas gracias la verdad es la primera vez que uso esta plataforma y no se bien su funcionamiento pero creo que ya agregue el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente sea por la variable estática. De esa forma no puedes distinguir qué enemigo debería destruirse.

De ahora en adelante evita usar variables estáticas. Un caso en el que podría ser útil es como forma de conocer si el juego está pausado. Aún así, creo que un Singleton sería mejor.

La mayoría de las veces deberías guardar una referencia a la instancia de interés y acceder a los datos mediante propiedades o métodos. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Enemigo : MonoBehaviour
{
    int vida = 4;

    public int Vida => vida;
    public bool Derrotado => vida == 0;

    void Update(){
        if (Derrotado)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
} 

public class BarraDeVidaEnemigo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Slider slider;
    // SerializeField te permite asignar las variables privadas desde el editor
    [SerializeField] Enemigo enemigo;

    void Start() {
        slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
    }

    void Update() {
        slider.value = enemigo.Vida;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una variable `static` es una variable de la clase (no del objeto), por este motivo tu puedes acceder a dicho valor sin usar la instancia del objeto, es decir directamente desde la clase: `BarraDeVidaEnemigo.enemigoDerrotado`

Esto provoca que todos los objetos del tipo `BarraDeVidaEnemigo` comparte el mismo valor, por lo cual cuando muere un enemigo mueren todos.

Debes cambiar:

```
public static bool enemigoDerrotado = false;
```

Por:

```
public bool enemigoDerrotado = false;
```

Y luego en el otro script debes buscar la instancia `BarraDeVidaEnemigo` del mismo `GameObject`, es decir cambiar esto:

```
if (BarraDeVidaEnemigo.enemigoDerrotado)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Por esto:

```
if (gameObject.GetComponent<BarraDeVidaEnemigo>().enemigoDerrotado)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: También puedes haberlo encontrado previamente o asignado desde el editor.